# Parse String DateTime

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to parse a String into Date time. However, I am getting an error at runtime.

Code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String date = LocalDate
                  .parse("2015-11-29")
                  .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html): *"ISO_DATE_TIME Date and time with ZoneId '2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]'"*, perhaps you should be using *"ISO_LOCAL_DATE ISO Local Date '2011-12-03'"*

Answer (score 5):

`ISO_DATE_TIME` has the format pattern [`2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_DATE_TIME). You could use `ISO_LOCALDATE`

```
String date = LocalDate.parse("2015-11-29").format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
```